# Python sphinx does not document a simple module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to document a very simple python module in HTML using sphinx. I have the following directory structure:

```
Test
    - test
        - __init__.py
        - test.rst
    - docs
        - conf.py
        - index.rst
        - make.bat
        - Makefile
        < a few directories >
```

I ran sphinx-quickstart in the Test/docs folder which generated the above files and directories. These are the contents of some of the files and modifications:

test/__ init __.py

```
"""
Modules docs
"""

def myfunc():
    """
    Function docs
    """
    print("Hello")
```

test/test.rst:

```
test package
============

Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: test
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

docs/index.rst:

```
.. TestProject documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Oct 29 20:46:31 2021.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to TestProject's documentation!
=======================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. automodule::test
   ::members::

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

docs/conf.py: (comments removed)

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))   

project = 'TestProject'
copyright = '2021, TestAuthor'
author = 'TestAuthor'

release = '1'

extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary"
]

templates_path = ['_templates']

exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Then I ran in the docs folder: make html

Test/docs/_build/html/genindex.html is empty with the word Index at the top
Test/docs/_build/html/py-modindex.html does not exist

I want to document the myfunc() function in the test module. I seem to be messing up somewhere and I tried many many things but could not get the html pages to show anything.

The automodule directive in the test.rst inside the test python module directory should have worked I think. I also have a automodule::test in index.rst and I have added the parent directory in sys.path in conf.py and enabled some extensions in it from what I read up.

Comment: Which command did you try to generate the doc?

Comment: In the docs folder: make html

Comment: Could you try this from the python project folder : `sphinx-apidoc -o docs/ test --implicit-namespace`

Comment: I just tried it from Test folder. Here is the exact output: 
Creating file docs/test.rst.
Creating file docs/modules.rst.   Wow! It worked now when I ran the "make html" command. Thanks so much!! There is this line in the output of "make html" : checking consistency... E:\Code\Python\Test\docs\modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree   I will try to add it in the index.rst.